# How to draw Receiver Operating Characteristics (ROC) of 34 video sequences using MatLab

Tags: matlab, roc, image-processing, auc

I am working on video processing using MatLab R2017a. I have datasets containing 34 video sequences. I have to calculate the AUC of this datasets. As I know AUC is dependent upon the ROC. And ROC is a graph between TPR and FPR on different thresholds.

Now I have a question, how will I draw ROC for these 34 video sequences using different threshold?

As far as I understand, on a single threshold, I will calculate the TPR and FPR of each 34 videos. And I will have 34 TPR and 34 FPR. With help of it I can draw ROC, then what about the different thresholds?

Kindly guide me on this.